# Is attributes() a function in R?

Tags: r

Help files call `attributes()` a function. Its syntax looks like a function call. Even `class(attributes)` calls it a function.

But I see I can assign something to `attributes(myobject)`, which seems unusual. For example, I cannot assign anything to `log(myobject)`.

So what is the proper name for "functions" like `attributes()`? Are there any other examples of it? How do you tell them apart from regular functions? (Other than trying `supposedfunction(x)<-0`, that is.)

Finally, I guess `attributes()` implementation overrides the assignment operator, in order to become a destination for assignments. Am I right? Is there any usable guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good observation Indeed. It's an example of **replacement function**, if you see closely and type `apropos('attributes')` in your R console, It will return

```
 "attributes"                        
 "attributes<-"
```

along with other outputs.

So, basically the place where you are able to assign on the left sign of assignment operator, you are not calling `attributes`, you are actually calling `attributes<-` , There are many functions in R like that for example: `names(), colnames(), length()` etc. In your example `log` doesn't have any replacement counterpart hence it doesn't work the way you anticipated.

Definiton(from advanced R book link given below):

> Replacement functions act like they modify their arguments in place,
>   and have the special name xxx<-. They typically have two arguments (x
>   and value), although they can have more, and they must return the
>   modified object

If you want to see the list of these functions you can do : 
`apropos('<-$')` and you can check out similar functions, which has similar kind of properties.

You can read about it [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment)

I am hopeful that this solves your problem.

Comment: Terse clarity: `attributes(x) <- c(...)` is equivalent to `\`attributes<-\`(x, c(...))`.